# Why do i get the exception here?

Tags: java

This is the constructor of my class . With the following code :

```
public tester {
    setTitle("tester");
    initComponents();
    jTextArea6.setEditable(false);
    jEditorPane1.setEditable(false);
}
```

Every thing is fine . But with this code ,

```
public tester() {
    setTitle("tester");
    jTextArea6.setEditable(false);
    jEditorPane1.setEditable(false);
    initComponents();

}
```

i get the following exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tester.tester.<init>(tester.java:31)
at tester.tester$35.run(tester.java:1389)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:660)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Why this is so ?

Comment: maybe you're trying to setEditable(false) objects that don't exist yet?

Comment: For better clarity, please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  If this question had done so, people who are answering would not have had to jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code (the definition of `initComponents` in particular, plus the definition of the fields) it's not possible to be 100% certain.

But it's almost definitely the case that the `initComponents()` method sets the value of `jTextArea6` and/or `jEditorPane1`.  In the second example you're trying to dereference these fields *before* they're set; which means they'd have the default value of `null`, and so would cause the NullPointerException to be thrown when you try to invoke methods on them.

Obviously one fix is to leave things as they are, perhaps with a comment stating

```
// Note - this method call initialises the fields.  DO NOT REORDER!!!
```

But a better solution is to get the compiler to check these things for you.  If the two fields don't ever change (i.e. they're set up once and for all within the constructor), then you can and arguably should declare them `final`.  In addition to this being very clear to others that they don't have to consider the possibility of these fields changing, it means that they won't have default values assigned initially, and the compiler will not let you dereference them before they've been assigned.

Comment: I am using netbeans for my program.It places init methid automatically.What does init actually do ?

Answer (score 4):

Because `jTextArea6` and `jEditorPane1` are being initialized by `initComponents`. You cannot access them before that - they are null. That's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

in initcomponents these objects are created? Therefore, it should be called first?

Answer (score 0):

because in  initComponents(); you instates objects of
             jTextArea6          jEditorPane1

Answer (score 0):

```
public tester() {
  setTitle("tester");
  jTextArea6.setEditable(false);  //jTextArea6 might be null
  jEditorPane1.setEditable(false); //jEditorPane1 might be null
  initComponents(); //I assume you're creating your components here, thus jTextArea6 and jEditorPane1 would be non-null after this line only
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because the method `initComponents()` initializes variables `jTextArea6` and/or `jEditorPane1`. Calling methods before initialization is throwing a `NullPointerException`